# A good html capable richedit replacement for winforms?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, editor, controls

Can anyone recommend a html replacement for a winforms (c#) richedit control?

I would like a control like the build in richedit control, that just use HTML instead of rtf to store the text. I don't want it to edit HTML, just to present a editor with images and styled text that store the result in html.

I would prefer a free control, but if there aren't any good control a commercial control would be acceptable too.

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a WPF control is an option, look at this control:  http://wpfricheditorlibrary.codeplex.com/

There is an excellent open-source library for converting RTF to HTML... you could couple this with either the built-in richedit control, or use one of the many extended controls to achieve your goal.  You'd just need to wire the two together, which isn't that hard.

The RTF to HTML library:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/RtfConverter.aspx

A couple of the extended RTF controls:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/scottlysle/wordprocessor02042007234628pm/wordprocessor.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/WinFormsCodeBox.aspx

HTH ~ James