# Windows Form TextBox to show images

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I currently have a Windows Form project where I have created a simple chat application. Currently the chat is output to a multi line text box, however I want to now enhance it a little and add some styling. In time I wish to have some image, format it nicely and perhaps some HTML (although this isnt vital) in the future. I am just wondering what I should use to achieve this. I did think of updating a HTML page and then reload it with each new message, but this wouldn't give a very good user experience. I have also looked at the richtextbox class but this seems to be a little limited for what I am after. I am hoping some one can point me in the right direction as to what to use.

I am trying to achieve something similar as what I have highlighted in red:

[image]

Comment: Use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

Comment: HTML control for winforms  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456787/a-good-html-capable-richedit-replacement-for-winforms

Comment: One of the many compelling reasons to switch to WPF from WinForms...

Comment: 100% agree with @programmer93, forget winforms you can achieve that with a simple `ListBox` and some `DataTemplates` in WPF. Check [this sample chat client](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25261/A-WCF-WPF-Chat-Application)

Comment: maybe you can create your own component - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228287(v=vs.90).aspx. I haven't used it my self. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861022/how-to-create-new-components-in-visual-studio-2010 or has programmer93 and HighCore strongly advised you, to use wpf.

Comment: I've been looking into WPF, but read some sources saying this is being replaced by HTML5? Also, if I go down the modo route, is there a method you can suggest to achieve this is GTK or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

While some of the other comments indicate that WPF is well suited to this, in the real world, it is not always possible or desirable to switch.

A regular owner-drawn list box is well suited to this purpose.

To create one, simply set the DrawMode on the list box to OwnerDrawVariable, e.g.

```
list.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
```

Then you just need to provide two event handlers, the first to measure the item (tell the list box how tall the item will be), and another to actually render it.  e.g.

```
this.list.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.list_DrawItem);
this.list.MeasureItem += new System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventHandler(this.list_MeasureItem);
```

Rendering an image into the list is fairly simple with GDI+ DrawImage (where g is your graphics context_:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.FromFile("test.jpg");
Rectangle source = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
Rectangle dest = source;
g.DrawImage(bmp, dest, source, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

This is a sample Windows Form which has an owner-drawn list box of all fonts on the system, producing variable-height owner-drawn list items:
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Font_Display
{
    public class Test : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private Font head;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox list;
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

        public Test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            head = new Font("Arial", 10, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing) {
                if (components != null) {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.list = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // list
            // 
            this.list.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
            this.list.IntegralHeight = false;
            this.list.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.list.Name = "list";
            this.list.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(604, 323);
            this.list.TabIndex = 0;
            this.list.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.list_DrawItem);
            this.list.MeasureItem += new System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventHandler(this.list_MeasureItem);
            // 
            // Test
            // 
            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(6, 15);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 358);
            this.Controls.Add(this.list);
            this.Name = "Test";
            this.Text = "Display";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Test_Load);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Display_Resize);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Test());
        }

        private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                // Loop all font families
                FontFamily[] families = FontFamily.Families;
                foreach (FontFamily family in families) {
                    try { list.Items.Add(new Font(family, 20, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)); continue; }
                    catch { }
                }

                Display_Resize(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch {
            }
        }

        private void Display_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;
            list.SetBounds(list.Left,
                list.Top,
                r.Width - (list.Left * 2),
                r.Height - (list.Top + list.Left));
        }

        public string TextValue = "Example String";

        public StringFormat Format
        {
            get
            {
                StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericTypographic;
                format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
                return format;
            }
        }

        private void list_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Brush back = null;
            Brush fore = null;
            Brush htext = null;
            Rectangle r;

            try {
                Font font = (Font)list.Items[e.Index];

                // Loop
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) != 0) {
                    back = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkBlue);
                    fore = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    htext = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange);
                }
                else {
                    back = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
                    fore = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                    htext = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkRed);
                }

                // Fill the rect
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(back, e.Bounds);

                // Get the size of the header
                SizeF szHeader = e.Graphics.MeasureString(font.Name, head, int.MaxValue, Format);
                SizeF szText = e.Graphics.MeasureString(TextValue, font, int.MaxValue, Format);

                // Draw the string
                r = e.Bounds;
                r.Height = (int)szHeader.Height;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, head, htext, r, Format);

                // Draw the string
                r = e.Bounds;
                r.Y = (int)(e.Bounds.Y + szHeader.Height);
                r.Height = (int)szText.Height;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(TextValue, font, fore, r, Format);
            }
            catch {
            }
            finally {
                if (fore != null) fore.Dispose();
                if (back != null) back.Dispose();
                if (htext != null) htext.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void list_MeasureItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                Font font = (Font)list.Items[e.Index];
                SizeF szHeader = e.Graphics.MeasureString(font.Name, head, int.MaxValue, Format);
                SizeF szText = e.Graphics.MeasureString(TextValue, font, int.MaxValue, Format);

                // Return it
                e.ItemHeight = (int)(szText.Height + szHeader.Height);
                e.ItemWidth = (int)Math.Max(szText.Width, szHeader.Width);
            }
            catch {
            }
        }
    }
}
```